# How to make type safe filtration in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have different types of entities in db and I want to be able to filter them by some conditions in a type safe way. I'm using Slick for db access, but it doesn't really matter I think.

For example, let's say I have User and Post entities. User has id and email fields, Post has id and title fields.

Right now I'm using ADT to represent filters. Looks like this:

```
sealed trait Filter {

  def byId(id: Long): Filter = and(ById(id))

  def byEmail(email: String): Filter = and(ByEmail(email))

  def byTitle(title: String): Filter = and(ByTitle(title))

  def and(other: Filter): Filter = And(this, other)

}

object Filter {
  def apply(): Filter = NoFilter
}

case class ById(id: Long) extends Filter

case class ByEmail(email: String) extends Filter 

case class ByTitle(title: String) extends Filter

case class And(a: Filter, b: Filter) extends Filter

case object NoFilter extends Filter
```

And interpreter for it in UserDao. PostDao looks the same:

```
trait Dao[A] {
  def find(filter: Filter, offset: Int, limit: Int):Seq[A]
}

object UserDao extends Dao[User]{

  override def find(filter: Filter, offset: Int, limit: Int): Seq[Any] = {
    filterTable(filter).drop(offset).take(limit).result
  }

  private def filterTable(table: Query[UserTable, User, Seq], filter: Filter): Query[UserTable, User, Seq] =
    filter match {
      case ById(id) => table.filter(_.id === id)
      case ByEmail(email) => table.filter(_.email === email)
      case And(a, b) => filterTable(filterTable(table, a), b)
      case NoFilter => table
      case other =>
        log.warn(s"Filter not supported $other")
        table
    }
}
```

And is used by generic service:

```
class Service[A](dao: Dao[A]) {
  def find(filter: Filter): Seq[A] = {
    // do some stuff
    dao.find(filter, offset = 0, limit = 100)
    // do some other stuff
  }
}
```

As you see it works, but it's not type safe. Although filtering users by title won't fail it doesn't make sense and could be cause of a bug. I thought maybe I create different sets of ADT for different entities, but then I will have to duplicate filters which are very similar(id filter, for example). So in summary I want to have filters which:

1. Type safe. You can't create Filter `ByTitle` for User
2. You don't need to duplicate common filters like `ById`, `And`, `Or`, `In` and so on.

How can I do it? Maybe ADT is not what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a bunch of "marker" traits for your domain objects, then you can parametrize your `Filter` type with the type of data it can be filtering:

```
  trait Filter[-T] 

  case class ById(id: Long) extends Filter[HasId]
  case class ByEmail(email: String) extends Filter[HasEmail]
  case class ByTitle(title: String) extends Filter[HasTitle]
  case class And[A, B](a: Filter[A], b: Filter[B]) extends Filter[A with B]
  case class Or[A, B](a: Filter[A], b: Filter[B]) extends Filter[A with B]
```

Now, you can declare `filterTable` to constrain the type of filter it will accept:

```
def filterTable(table: Query[UserTable, User, Seq], filter: Filter[User]) = ...
```

So, `filterTable(myTable, ById(1) and ByEmail("foo"))` will compile, but
`filterTable(myTable, ByTitle("foo"))` will not.

Comment: Thank you! It's very interesting approach and could work. Although I don't really want to add such traits to my domain objects, but I think there could be a workaround.  One thing that bothers me is non exhaustive pattern match. Does this approach have exhaustive pattern match? I'll try it today and if it works I accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, if you make `Filter` trait sealed, the match will be exhaustive, yes. 
You can avoid having to add traits to domain objects by using typeclasses ... but (1) that's a lot more  typing, and a lot more "magic" going on for the reader or the code, so, I don't usually recommend it as long as there are other options (namely, you have control over your domain object definitions), and (2) I can't think of a way to make the match exhaustive in that case.